Remote Desktop Control Access for multiple users
I am new to the Linux universe. I installed Arch on a desktop at my office. I am trying to set up a remote desktop control from my Windows 10 to Arch linux.
I've installed Rustdesk which works fine. The problem being that Rustdesk does not manage sessions. What I want to achieve is to gain remote control the same want Remote Desktop Control work with Windows Server. Each user opens it own session when connecting remotely.
I tried to use xrdp but no matter what I do, the RDC from Windows log in successfully but always fails to start X Server.
My Arch installation uses X System and Budgie Desktop.
I installed lightdm too but disabled it (thinking it might be the cause of the failure, but nothing)
I would like a step by step guide to a working solution. I am open to other technologies than xrdp if there are some.
Thanks in advance.

a paid for solution that I use at work is NICE-DCV, having the benefit of graphics hardware acceleration over the network of the vnc connection
fundamentally you want to run a VNC session (virtual network computing).  I've used nicedcv so long I forget how to make use of the basic free vnc {tigervnc} that comes with [redhat] linux.
There is also things like xming, and X11 over ssh, but the basics for what it sounds like you want to do is VNC, where each user will have their own vnc remote session they can connect to.
also look at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_the_desktop_environment_in_rhel_8/accessing-the-desktop-remotely_using-the-desktop-environment-in-rhel-8
I am not familiar with Arch linux, if you are not dead set on needing Arch then Rocky Linux the free redhat is the way to go.  There are many online writeups on Linux VNC.  From Windows you would either run a vnc-client.exe program in windows to connect to your linux vnc session, and can sometimes even use firefox or chrome web browser to connect to your vnc session and have the linux gnome desktop within the browser window as if you were sitting at the console of a linux system with full desktop graphics.

What I want to achieve is to gain remote control the same want Remote Desktop Control work with Windows Server.

have a snickers :)

Thanks @ron I'll read about VNC.
